What is the effect of suction surface pressure coefficient on lift under flow separation?
Quick question. Lets say we are looking at the CP plot of the 13 degree angle of attack, seen in the image below:

Now, let's say we force separation right after that suction peak. This will mean we have a constant lower pressure than the fully attached case... and doesnt this mean we should have more lift?

Reason I ask is that I have heard that by intentionally forcing separation towards the rear of an airfoil, you can increase its aft loading and thus overall lift. So I was thinking that we could apply that near where the peak is to have lower pressure over a larger %chord.
For example, look at this cylinder which has separated flow. The Cp coefficient along the aft side is constant ~-0.5 for High Re and ~-1.3 for Low Re due to separation…

Or maybe I am answering my own question here, but if we force separation, then our suction peak will be significantly reduced as we only get the peak due to the pressure recovery - which is also seen in the cylinder photos
Edited to show Cp of a Cylinder with attached and separated flow.

Like sophit said... pretty much in a nutshell...

@ThomasPerry: But then how come for a cylinder with separated flow, the Cp stays constant when you have separation? https://www.aerodynamics4students.com/fluid-mechanics/cylinder_flow_pressures.gif

Your assumptions about suction peak and low pressure to the trailing edge are both wrong. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43221/what-is-the-effect-of-flow-separation-on-lift-pressure-distribution-and-drag explains that separation makes the airfoil behave as if it were longer, thicker and had less camber. This reduces the negative pressure on the rear of the airfoil, thus also reducing the suction peak. The resulting curve looks more like your fully separated flow curve, but at a lower angle of attack.

@aerokid95 There is no circulation.  The $C_p$ so encountered is within the turbulent wake.  The presence of circulation, particularly in the case of a cylinder, will largely preclude the development of separation. Note that when separation and stall occurs on an airfoil, circulation is lost and the $C_p$ rises in the wake similar to your illustration.  Excellent question!

Let's see how this works. Attachment of the flow through the region of pressure recovery is necessary to preclude stall. Here is the velocity profile of an airfoil designed to intentionally force separation to the trailing edge and, in fact, preclude separation altogether. Flow is from left to right in the illustration.   As air flows from the nose of the airfoil (left) toward the trailing edge (right), the velocity of the flow is accelerated to a minimum value of $C_p$.  If the Reynolds number is sufficiently high and the contour surface clean and smooth, this is a region of laminar flow. At the point where the velocity profile encounters pressure recovery, the flow begins to decelerate and becomes turbulent.  The characterization of the flow as laminar or turbulent specifically refers to the nature of the flow in the boundary layer of flow at the surface of the airfoil contour. When separation of the turbulent boundary layer occurs, the airfoil is said to stall.
In this region of pressure recovery, the upwardly concave portion of the velocity profile promotes turbulent boundary-layer attachment meaning that turbulent separation and consequent stall, is precluded.  This concave portion indicates that the abrupt deceleration of the flow is being relaxed as the flows progresses toward the trailing edge.  B.S. Stratford examined this property in the pressure recovery and attachment of turbulent flow along the wall of a wind tunnel where the wall of interest could be distorted to preclude turbulent separation.  Robert Liebeck investigated airfoil design using this property in the mid-1970s. He wanted to examine airfoils having significant lift properties due to delayed stall. F.X. Wortmann was well aware of this aspect regarding concavity in the recovery region of the velocity profile, and initially investigated airfoils designed with this recovery property in the early-to-mid 1950s. His airfoils have been used extensively in many high-performance sailplanes and human-powered aircraft.
Lift is proportional to the area enclosed within the velocity profile.  When separation occurs forward of the trailing edge up to the velocity peak near the leading edge, the velocity profile becomes roughly flat over a major portion of the airfoil chord at a $C_p$ value of -0.4, more or less.  Consequently, the area enclosed within the velocity profile is significantly reduced, meaning that airfoil lift is reduced. This is the consequence of stall.
To gain as much lift as possible means that the designer must make the enclosed area as large as possible thereby pushing the recovery portion as close to the trailing edge as possible. However, this reaches a practical limit.  Consequently, the design of wings having favorable lift characteristics typically have the placement of minimum pressure sufficiently forward to accommodate an adequate range in angles of attack while giving favorable stalling characteristics.


let's say we force separation right after that suction peak. This will mean we have a constant lower pressure than the fully attached case... and doesn't this mean we should have more lift?

Not really
If we force separation then (at least) three things would happen:

This artificially triggered "suction" would act on the rear portion of the airfoil which normally points upward and backward; the relevant resulting aerodynamic force would therefore also point upward - adding up to the lift as you guessed - but also backward - adding up to the drag.
In subsonic flows, what happens downstream influences also what happens upstream; this means that the stalled region on the backward part of the airfoil would change the forward distribution of suction, basically reducing its value: the $C_p$ there would reach maybe only -1 instead of the -4 of your picture.
The redistribution of $C_p$ on the backward part of the airfoil would increase the pitching moment generated by the airfoil, which would need to be counteracted increasing the download on the tail (at least on a conventional airplane) with a relevant increase in the so-called trim drag.

At the end you wouldn't obtain a higher lift rather a higher drag.

But how come, over here when you see flow separating on a cylinder, the Cp stays constant after separation? It doesn’t drop to 0. https://www.aerodynamics4students.com/fluid-mechanics/cylinder_flow_pressures.gif

@aerokid95 right, I didn't really explained myself well, let me rework my answer
